# htaccess rule for subfolders in subdomain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have created a subdomain to point to a folder on my root directory like this;

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

I can now access files of the `/blog` folder like this `http://blog.example.co.uk/index.php`

The `/blog` folder contains a `/php` folder containing scripts.
I'm unable to access the `/php` folder like this `http://blog.example.co.uk/php/test.php`

This doesn't work. For me to access them I have to do this `http://www.example.co.uk/blog/php/test.php`

Below is my current `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
### Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
### Prevent rules on script folder in root /php & /blog/php because I remove .php extension from all files
RewriteRule ^(php|blog/php)($|/) - [L]
### To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
### To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
### My subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Now I need to create a rule to point `http://blog.example.co.uk/php` to `/blog/php`

When I try to access files in the /php now I get a File Not Found error

Thanks

**This is my complete htaccess. The pretty url rules are not working.**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

### Blog subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]

### Careers subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^careers\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/careers/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /careers/$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^(php|blog/php|careers/php|vendors|blog/vendors)($|/) - [L]

# To remove index.php or index.html from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ "/$1" [NC,R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php?$ "/$1" [NC,R=301,NE,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one (BLOG)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+post(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+author(?:\.php)?\?author=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /author/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one (CAREERS)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+role(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)&role=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /role/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one (BLOG)
RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&title=%2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&title=%2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^author/([\w-]+)?$ author.php?author=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one (CAREERS)
RewriteRule ^role/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ role.php?id=$1&role=%2 [L,QSA,NC]

### Error 404 redirect
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these rules:

```
### Error 404 redirect
ErrorDocument 404 /404page.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one (BLOG)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+post(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /post/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+category(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)&title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /category/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+author(?:\.php)?\?author=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /author/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one (CAREERS)
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+role(?:\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+)&role=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /role/%1/%2? [R=302,L,NE]

# To remove index.php or index.html from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.html?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.html?$ /$1 [NC,R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php?$ /$1 [NC,R=301,NE,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.html to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one (BLOG)
RewriteRule ^post/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^category/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ category.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^author/([\w-]+)?$ author.php?author=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one (CAREERS)
RewriteRule ^role/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ role.php?id=$1&role=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

### Blog subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog/$1 [L]

### Careers subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^careers\.example\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/careers/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ careers/$1 [L]    

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks guru. Your code works but it has broken the pretty url code you helped me with yesterday. See my edits please and help. Thank you :)

Comment: Still no joy `http://blog.example.co.uk/post/153/title-of-post` goes to `Error 500` :(

Comment: With every change you're bringing new URLs. What is happening with `http://blog.example.co.uk/php/test.php` URL? If getting 500 then check Apache error.log and report the error text here

Comment: That url was giving Error 500 and your initial answer fixed that.
But then it broke my friendly url and now they are giving Error 500.

Comment: There is no way anyone can test that kind of .htaccess to give you a better answer. You will need to provide lot of details from your side. What URLs do you want to support, how they are handled internally, content of `error.log` for 500 errors etc. Or shorten it to the problem area.

Comment: `RewriteCond: NoCase option for non-regex pattern '-f' is not supported and will be ignored`

Comment: That is just a warning not real error. Anyway I've updated it one last time.

Comment: Managed to get this working. All the rules were correct. Just had to rearrange them. Thanks again. Marking as answer.